# delete column from one table created while joining two tables using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two temptables joined by using innerjoin and code as follows

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table3') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp_table3

select VendorNumber,stuff( (select distinct ','+dbo.vendordata.InvoiceStatus
                               from dbo.vendordata
                               where dbo.vendordata.VendorNumber = dbo.vendordata.VendorNumber 
                               for xml path('')
                              ), 1, 1, ''
                            ) as InvoiceStatus
into #temp_table3
from dbo.vendordata
group by VendorNumber


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table4') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp_table4

select VendorNumber, sum(EY_AmountIncl_LC) AmountIncl_LC,
       sum(EY_AmountExcl_LC) AmountExcl_LC, max(EY_datedocumented) Datedocumented
into #temp_table4
from dbo.vendordata
group by VendorNumber

select * 
from #temp_table3 T inner join 
     #temp_table4 V 
     on T.vendorNumber = V.VendorNumber
```

Now output is as follows

```
VendorNumber  Invoicestatus      VendorNumber   EY_AmountIncl   EY_AmountExcl     EY_datedocumented
50000471     V-Parked S-Noted     50000471        281072           281072           00:00.0
5200991      V-Parked S-Noted     5200991         80000            80000            00:00.0
5200595      V-Parked S-Noted     5200595         72401.6         72401.6           00:00.0
```

How to remove the vendor number which is repeated twice can any one help?

Comment: This seams not to be valid MySQL code.. `for xml path('')` and `OBJECT_ID` and `#` are SQL Server (MSSQL).. It seams you have tagged the wrong database here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the last select

Insetead of select *  from  ....

select only the columns you need eg:

```
select T.VendorNumber, T.InvoiceStatus, V.AmountIncl_LC, 
       V.AmountExcl_LC, V.Datedocumented
from #temp_table3 T inner join 
     #temp_table4 V 
     on T.vendorNumber = V.VendorNumber
```